# adding a width & height to the image inside of a Response.Write

Tags: asp-classic

Trying to add a width and height to the image inside of this script. For some reason, it's giving me an error when uploading. Here is the script below.

```
<% Response.Write("<img src=""/control/images/CONF" & imageurl & ".jpg"" alt=""" & cname & """>") %>
```

trying to get a hang of ASP. Thanks!

Comment: Check this out [add height and width](http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Image-Width-and-Height-Using-HTML) so you should just add it after alt="" in your image tags.

Comment: Hi @MatthewThorne i believe because its inside of the response.write tags, its not giving me the same effects of being inside the img tags. It still gives me an error.

Comment: try using single qoutes outside '    and double qoutes on the inside " .

Comment: for some reason its accepting the script with no error , but the image isn't decreasing. any ideas? @MatthewThorne

Comment: so the single qoutes worked then? and have you been debugging it into the browser.  can you update what the current code is you are using?

Comment: hi @MatthewThorne like I mentioned before. It didn't give me an error, but also didn't solve the problem. The answer below with the double quotes inside of the script is what worked best! Thanks again for your help and effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% Response.Write("<img width=""100px"" height=""200px"" src=""/control/images/CONF" & imageurl & ".jpg"" alt=""" & cname & """>") %>
```

Comment: Yes it does - like the other answer

Comment: Sorry, I clicked on the wrong button. Can you expand the answer? I find code only answers more complicated to compare with the question and understand, in particular when the code line is very long (as in this case).

Comment: This method is what helped me solve the problem! Thank you very much. I appreciate the help and advice! @JanuszJasinski

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Use the `height` and `width` attributes in the `img` tag:

```
Response.Write "<img height=120px width=100% />"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to help you get an idea of how to use semi-quotes within quotes:

```
response.write ("<img height='120' width='120' src='/images/yomamma.jpg' target='_NEW'>")
```

Comment: hi @scotterMonkey . I tried the single quotes within the other quotes and didn't come up with an error, but it didn't make the image any smaller. The double quotes like the answer above is what worked best! Thank you for your comment and help!